# Is there a way to narrow a type at compile time?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to narrow a union type using a conditional type definition but no matter how hard I try I can't comprehend why this code is failing :

```js
const makeEventA = (value: number) => ({ _tag: "a" as const, payload: value })
type EventA = ReturnType<typeof makeEventA>
const makeEventB = (value: string) => ({ _tag: "b" as const, payload: value })
type EventB = ReturnType<typeof makeEventB>

type AnyEvent = EventA | EventB;

type AnyEventTag = AnyEvent["_tag"];

type FindByTag<A, B extends AnyEventTag> = A extends { _tag: B } ? A : never;

type Mapping = {
  [K in AnyEventTag]?: (ev: FindByTag<AnyEvent, K>) => Promise<void>;
};

const execute = (m: Mapping) => (ev: AnyEvent) => {
  const handler = m[ev._tag];
  if (handler) {
    handler(ev);
  }
};
```

My call `handler(ev)` generates this:

```
Argument of type 'AnyEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  The intersection 'EventA & EventB' was reduced to 'never' because property '_tag' has conflicting types in some constituents.
    Type 'EventA' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Here is a link to a sandbox with the code =>
https://codesandbox.io/embed/dank-dawn-ilcxt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=editor

Can someone explain to me why I'm wrong?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WG6lKm) meet your needs? You're running into the issue at [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) which will more or less be addressed in TS4.6 in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) (although the code in my link above works in TS4.5) via refactoring to a "distributed object type".  Please test and let me know if something doesn't work for you; otherwise I can write up an answer explaining the situation.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for your comment! This looks promising but I can't rewrite all my events using this method. I need to have an union of all my events and be able to discriminate from them because their payload differ one from another depending on the tag. In my example I removed the payloads on purpose for simplification reasons but in real life my events are much more complex.

Comment: You can certainly express a mapping from tag to payload if you are willing to make the example a [mre] (doesn't have to be "much more complex" here, just complex enough so that a potential solution isn't dismissed, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wk5njN) maybe)?.  You can always just use a type assertion (see ms/TS#30581 link in first comment) and move on with your life, but if you want type safety then a distributed object should work.  If you really can't rewrite things that way then I can still write up an answer going over the issues involved here.  Let me know.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for all the work you've been putting in this issue. I read the long list of comment and I understand much better why this isn't working now.
I think I'm going with type assertion for now but I'm going to edit my code in order to show you my problem in a more understandable way.

Comment: @jcalz here a link to a [playground](http://shorturl.at/egDZ0) to show you a simplified version of my events

Comment: An [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAwge0QMwJYHMA88SwAzlBAB7BIAmZA3lANbaI0BcUJwATq7lAC+APigBeKPQBQUWVADaMKK1gJkZAIZkY8gEQs2ugLpHOACghrgnGAEpxouGmw0A3FMFSpoSFADKAI4Arho8EETI4pLMrBxQuiTBoRC6ADRQFJyIQQC2AEYQPOkgWbkFPELuPtAo2DwAxgA24VZRjAZxuvV1TSnpPBo02EEkpfmFlV7VUOhYeFERqBg4BIEhYYtQAD4zPc2LwlIA9EdyAHoA-EA) with a similar setup.

Comment: @Ephasme that url (http://shorturl.at/egDZ0) doesn't go anywhere useful for me.  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvY0Ym) represent what you're doing well enough (taken from the edited question).

Comment: Well, hopefully it's close enough...

Comment: Yeah I think the last proposal you sent could work for me, I'll try it today and keep you posted! Thanks a lot for all your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue here is that the compiler doesn't understand the fact that the type of `handler` is *correlated* with the type of `ev`; it sees each of them as independent [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for details.  So `handler(ev)` is an error because the compiler is worried about impossible "cross-correlated" situations. The compiler doesn't do what you do when faced with `handler(ev)` and analyze it multiple times for each possible `_tag` property of `ev`.  If it did do this, there wouldn't be a problem; indeed, you can force the compiler to go through such analysis by actually writing out redundant code:

```
const executeRedundant = (m: Mapping) => (ev: AnyEvent) => {
    if (ev._tag === "a") {
        const handler = m[ev._tag];
        if (handler) {
            handler(ev); // okay
        }
    } else {
        const handler = m[ev._tag];
        if (handler) {
            handler(ev); // okay
        }
    }
};
```

That's type safe, but blecch. Refactoring to redundant code doesn't scale.

---

If you're going to refactor your code for type safety, you could do it so that it's [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the `_tag` property.  You can use the approach presented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), where you represent your `AnyEvent` [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) as a "distributive object type":

```
type TagPayloadMap = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}
type AnyEventTag = keyof TagPayloadMap

type AnyEvent<K extends AnyEventTag = AnyEventTag> =
    { [P in K]: { _tag: P, payload: TagPayloadMap[P] } }[K]

const makeEvent = <K extends AnyEventTag>(tag: K) => (value: TagPayloadMap[K]): AnyEvent<K> => ({ _tag: tag, payload: value });
const makeEventA = makeEvent("a");
const makeEventB = makeEvent("b");

type EventA = AnyEvent<"a">;
type EventB = AnyEvent<"b">;

type Mapping<K extends AnyEventTag = AnyEventTag> = {
    [P in K]?: (ev: AnyEvent<P>) => Promise<void>;
};
const execute = <K extends AnyEventTag>(m: Mapping<K>) => (ev: AnyEvent<K>) => {
    const handler = m[ev._tag];
    if (handler) {
        handler(ev); // okay
    }
};
```

That all works just fine now (even in TS4.5, although it will apparently be easier to call `execute()` in TS4.6+), and the compiler sees `handler(ev)` as acceptable because it's all generic in `K`.  The types `AnyEvent` and `Mapping`, etc are all the same, but depend on a `TagPayloadMap` type.  (Your `FindByTag` functionality is subsumed by the new `AnyEvent` type; you can write `AnyEvent<'a'>` instead of `FindByTag<AnyEvent, 'a'>`, for example.)

---

If you're *not* going to refactor your code because you are dependent on the current structure, then you're going to have to give up on having type safety.  The compiler just can't see that what you're doing is safe.  In such cases, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler not to worry too much about the types.  It shifts the burden of maintaining type safety away from the compiler (which is not up to the task) and onto you.  So triple-check that you're doing it right, and then assert away.

For example:

```
const executeAssert = (m: Mapping) => (ev: AnyEvent) => {
    const handler = m[ev._tag];
    if (handler) {
        (handler as (value: AnyEvent) => Promise<void>)(ev);
    }
};
```

Here we're saying that `handler` can be treated as a function that takes `AnyEvent`; this isn't strictly true, but it's a fairly harmless lie and it convinces the compiler that it's okay to call `handler(ev)`.  Again, it's not safe; you can pass in something other than `ev`, like a random `AnyEvent`, and the compiler won't bat an eye.  So you need to be careful.

---

So those are the options: refactor to be redundant; refactor to be generic; or use a type assertion to suppress the error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKUICcAuBLA9sEgN4BQSFS8hU2SYIA1hAKIBuEw2KSAvEgAo2IADYBXCAC4kwMWABGWAJR8AfIOJIA+thABzaQCIQhpCChUa2ADRI4ATxH4QAE2nDxyAL5LylbPYwyOyc3HxIAEoQ2GKYwAAqgRAAPAFB+ABm9EysHFwoqn4U1MC02cwhXABC4UKiEtK0mLjAeiq86gKaOvpG8qbmlqU2diCOzm5IHhJIPkVIacF52DX8UTFxiUGpSZnluaFVhfOLqMD2lXT8lzwAPkiXVQDcpCdJZxfL8frhKOeXAG1DD09IYALovN5BJAAMRaLiq9m+emSKFsNQgAA9sJwXBY-p9Qsj1PweFiccA8SRtLoDEgal4kAB+VBIaTACAcTCQygLd4AWRAMBgLT04TIvN5AIA0kgWh9LsiwUzpAJOdI4ZTEcjUf9lrZpap2uoAAqYfBgXAYZJsfC4FyqF68rw8yglMpYiDwMQ4qIuMSUkBcWpgaSC4Wi42CdUK5ZRiWSii4LJqtgAOhBfF4-GMhhUCcTvPddAAFkGXCIsOEwADORnaRD5oW5Smy5TK5h803m5Q2xWsKmlE6exQvN3R0gICIMCRx5Li0g+x3q7X0yDGyOk63yx2u5vJUuB5yh3PnXOx87IfMF57vTi0BgcCGw0KRa0o6npATLvG5wvD5gK51uuw6JsmggAXum4CABZgWHUnhfnqoRRmaFpWiktr2kag6gZKF6UC6pBjq8oCQLACDIAAIla2DNPIPoQC4ADy8gAFZenQBZ8tCyImmMTiuOG4pziA7JyIo3JzvIjR0aKeEERQpzfl8Pz8Mw9h7HxAkTOGry8spyFcMksrkri+JGdgyK-JZxJ8HOmgAiacpENKYLSN0tLSCatgOIJkzaeMQlCk5YKzLMMpgvpbpWPslzhCZk7YuZsZEvoqgCF5SDSh+0xSEggX+eGkVKEhhLGYaagaDSvQLPovk6a47j1N4J5FrFDAVMsPD8J1BxcAIuZtTFwxxcsqxjaEg39Ce0VKe8Nw2eV2DJLmjpQkshxLZcq39OtG1IOGb4oqZyWUhZy3WaStnpSJzZOS52XKqqMYqaEyQmkaVVoZa1pYQ6Cl4TemJeoxCWnRSVJvVwxICKGh2vqKJlfR00ZsGVO2Gr+zb-juVa9au9b6BuhbgTBeOdrO+4AbhSAAPR00g+CMGM57zERxGkEAA)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `handler` (ignoring the `undefined`, i.e. within the `if` block),
is either a map `EventA => Void<Promise>` or a map `EventB => Void<Promise>`, whereas the input `ev` is either of type `EventA` or `EventB`. So from the compiler's perspective, it could be, for example, that `handler` is of type `EventA => Promise<Void>`, while `ev` is of type `EventB`, which then are not compatible.  The type `FindByTag` does not reify an `AnyEvent` to an actual `EventA` or an `EventB` based on what `K` is.

Comment: do you have any idea how to make it work? Because when I try to use FindByTag on itself it does reify the type down to what I expect.
Doing `type AStar = FindByTag<AnyEvent, 'a'>` actually gives me back type A.